# prisma how to change model name and update that name across project?

Tags: prisma

my schema is like this

```js
model LoginSessions {
    id      Int      @id @unique @default(autoincrement())
    token   String   @default("") @db.VarChar(255)
    userId  String   @default("") @db.VarChar(255)
 
    @@map(name: "login_sessions")
}
```

my code is like this

```js
const ins = await prisma.loginSessions.create({
            data: { userId, token, role },
        })
```

Now I want to change the model name from `LoginSessions` to `Logs`.

That will leave a problem, all the code in the project still have `prisma.loginSessions` in it, it can't run. is there a way to do this automatically and cleanly ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by changing `log_sessions` to `Logs` in `model` property

maintain the map property to same as `log_sessions`

```
model Logs {
  id     Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  token  String  @default("") @db.VarChar(255)
  userId String  @default("") @db.VarChar(255)

  @@map(name: "login_sessions")
}
```

after this, you have to rename all the references into the code from `prisma.loginSessions` to `prisma.Logs`.

Comment: that's not what I'm asking , I'm not changing the table name, I', changing the model name.

Comment: is there any way to automatically rename the reference in entire project? I'm using vscode